# Vue 3: excluding fallthrough attributes from attrs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working on a custom input component which has a parent div and a label. I'd like to apply any classes to the parent div but I also want to make sure that any other fallthrough attributes get applied to the input component.

Here's a simplified version of my component

In `App.vue`

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import MyInput from './MyInput.vue'

const msg = ref('I only want the outer blue box')
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <my-input class="blue" aria-foo="foo" aria-bar="bar"/>
</template>

<style>
  .blue {
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 3px solid blue;
  }
</style>
```

In `MyInput.vue`

```
<template>
  <div :class="attrs.class">
    <input v-bind="attrs" >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  customOptions: {}
}
</script>

<script setup>
 import { useAttrs, computed } from 'vue'
 const attrs = useAttrs();
</script>
```

Is there a good way to get all the `attrs` except for the class? I tried making a copy of `attrs` using a `computed` but that didn't seem to work.

This is what I tried:

```
const inputAttrs = computed(()=>{
  let returnObj = {}
  for (attr in attrs) {
    if (attr !== 'class') {
      returnObj[attr] = attrs[attr]
    }
  }
  return returnObj;
})
```

Apparently `attr` in the for loop was not defined? Essentially I want the input to get the `aria-foo` and `aria-bar` attributes without the `class` property.

Here's a [Link to the SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) with the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that **attr** was not defined as you need to define it within the for() using the **for...in** syntax.

```
const inputAttrs = computed(()=>{
  let returnObj = {}
  // use const below
  for (const attr in attrs) {
    if (attr !== 'class') {
      returnObj[attr] = attrs[attr]
    }
  }
  return returnObj;
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Argh I can't believe I missed that. yeah it works *sigh*